# Getting a batch file's full path

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to create a batch file that uses (e.g. prints) its full path:

```
c:\tmp\foo> nice.bat

I am c:\tmp\foo\nice.bat
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use %~f0 (e.g. "echo %~f0").

Answer (score 4):

Use [%0 and some modifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 3):

%~dp0 from memory is the full path to the batch file.

**EDIT** For more variable substitution run `call /?`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 echo I am %~f0
```